# npm run doesn't open webpage but simply hangs in case of wrong element name, how to handle this kind of issue?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and did below mistake.

In this case `npm run` did open webpage but didn't show any console error and page hanged after some time.

Is there any plugin to capture this kind of basic error ? or how to capture this error in code itself ?

```
import React from 'react';

function Button() {
    return (
        <>
            <Button>New Quote</Button>
        </>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `<Button>New Quote</Button>` to `<button>New Quote</button>`

In React, You can't mount a component within itself

Comment: "..Is there any plugin to capture this kind of basic error ? or how to capture this error in code itself ?.."

Comment: eslint plugin can help. You can create your own rules or use predefined config rules from airbnb or google, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate eslint into your project to detect the such errors.

- [ https://blog.echobind.com/integrating-prettier-eslint-airbnb-style-guide-in-vscode-47f07b5d7d6a ]

Also in case, you're using vs-code as a code editor, it also supports eslint plugin and you will be able to detect such errors in code itself.

Thanks